# How to apply disk quota in ubuntu server on a VPS?

Tags: 10.04, server, filesystem, quota

I have a VPS with ubuntu server 10.04 installed on it.Now I want to have some shell users with limited home folder size.

It seems quota is the best way to do this, but all tutorials require editing **/etc/fstab** and add **usrquota** or **grpquota** to /home partition options.

As my /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
proc  /proc       proc    defaults    0    0 
none  /dev/pts    devpts  rw          0    0
```

how can I apply quota?

Answer (score 4):

Your VPS provider may be doing tricks at boot-time resulting in your `/etc/fstab` not needing the root filesystem listed. You can find the device and other details from the output of the `mount` command. If you add those details to your `/etc/fstab`, you may be able to add the `usrquota,grpquota` options there for the next reboot.

If that doesn't work for your VPS, you may be able to approximate those mount options by turning them on later in the boot process. For example, I use `usrjquota=aquota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0` on an ext3 filesystem. If I didn't have access to my `/etc/fstab`, I might try editing my `/etc/rc.local` and adding something like:

```
mount -o remount,usrjquota=aquota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0 /that/filesystem
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.here is the line related to the root partition in mount command output: "/dev/vzfs on / type vzfs (rw)".Should I add "/dev/vzfs / ..." to the fstab file?

Comment: It may help, but probably not. Try using the `rc.local` approach instead.